# Package inputenc error not understood

Tags: bibtex, unicode, input-encodings

There is an error I have that i absolutely don't understand: it comes from this article from which i am trying to include the reference:

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp993642l

```
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1158 ...benzene, naphthalene, and anthracene: 
                                                   crossed and
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 

[134] [135] [136]) [137] (./output.aux (./Titlepage.aux) (./Kurzzusammenfassung.aux) (./Acronyms_defs.aux) (./Own_publications.aux) (./Chapters/Introduction.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_1.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_2.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_3.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_3bis.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_4.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_5.aux) (./Chapters/Chapter_6.aux) (./Chapters/Conclusion.aux))
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `output.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 )
```

I am adding the reference myself:

```
@article{gonzalez_quantum_2000,
author = {Gonzalez, Carlos and Lim, Edward C.},
title = {A Quantum Chemistry Study of the van der Waals Dimers of Benzene, Naphthalene, and Anthracene:  Crossed and Parallel-Displaced Dimers of Very Similar Energies in the Linear Polyacenes},
journal = {The Journal of Physical Chemistry A},
volume = {104},
number = {13},
pages = {2953-2957},
year = {2000},
doi = {https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp993642l},
}
```

I have no idea what is the unicode character it cannot understand, i see none...
Thank you for your help!

Best,
A.

Comment: well you don't show the complete error so we can't know neither which unicode character is the problem but there is a U+2009 (thin space) after the colon, so my guess is that is the problem.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would add all the code you used, in order for us to be able to test it and see the full error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only showed the last part of the error message, you omitted the main part which reports the character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

and Anthracene:  Crossed

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character   (U+2009)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 and Anthracene: 
                       Crossed
? h
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 
?
```

you have a U+2009 (thin space)  at the point after the `:` marked by the line break.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

and Anthracene: Crossed

\end{document}
```

runs without error

Comment: Thank you all, indeed the space was the problem - sorry for not showing all, the error message and the code would have been quite long, i showed was I thought was more relevant. I will be more careful the next times :)